# Adicionar valor de uma SET list no MySQL

Tags: java, sql

Quero adicionar valores em uma 'lista'(valores separados por "," que depois será usado a função "split") no mysql, estou usando o este codigo: `UPDATE clans SET Admins = concat(Admins, ',', 'NomeDoJogador') WHERE Name = 'NomeDoClan'`, mas quando eu adiciono um valor, e a 'lista' está vazia, o "," é enviado antes do valor, e isto era apenas para acontecer se existisse mais de um valor valor na 'lista'. Código usado para remover um jogador da "lista", caso seja necessário: `UPDATE clans SET Admins = REPLACE(REPLACE(Admins, ',NomeDoJogador', ''), 'NomeDoJogador', '') WHERE Name = '" + _clanName + "'`

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de usar `CONCAT` use `CONCAT_WS`:

```
UPDATE clans SET Admins = CONCAT_WS(',', Admins, 'NomeDoJogador') WHERE Name = 'NomeDoClan'
```